# Installing Aperture from the App Store when a previous version is installed

Tags: mac-appstore, aperture, serial-number

I have installed Apple Aperture some time ago using a serial (likely pirated) that I searched for on the internet.

Now, I want to purchase a legal version through the App Store, but it is seeing the prior version as installed. When I try to buy it, the App Store will not let me complete the purchase or download.

Ive tried to completely remove it and reinstall using this tutorial:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1259711?start=0&tstart=0

The steps listed did not work for me and I would appreciate additional steps to help.

Comment: Try `find / -name "Aperture"` from the Terminal and delete what looks like it might be related to the current installation. I'm purposely not giving the rest of the command to delete it automatically.

Comment: +1 for a good question and wanting to upgrade to a legit version.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to drag the following to trash and then quit and re-launch the Mac App Store:

- `/Library/Application Support/ProApps/Aperture System ID`
- `/Applications/Aperture.app`

If restarting the app store does not work, a reboot should clear any remnants of the older licensed Aperture product and let you install. Apple support is also very helpful if you need assistance removing an old serial number from a Mac. You don't have to necessarily tell them *how* you got the old serial number if you feel it may make them or you uncomfortable. I can't imagine a scenario where they wouldn't be delighted to assist you in procuring a legitimate license of the latest version of Aperture.

You can also use the `mdfind` command to search the entire hard drive for files with Aperture in them. Be prepared for a lot of files. I've never heard of people needing to delete all the Aperture directories, but you might also look to move these to trash as well:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Aperture.plist 
~/Library/Caches/Aperture
~/Library/Application\ Support/Aperture
```